# returning a LPTSTR from an unmanaged C++ DLL that contains '\0' characters

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshalling

I have a C# gui calling an unmanaged C++ dll.  callbacks are used for dll -> gui messaging.

in the dll a LPTSTR is created that may contain '\0' characters.  that string needs to be passed back via a callback parameter to the gui, in full, via the callback.

unfortunately i can only get the string passed to the gui up until the null character.  seems the marshaling cuts the string.

```
// C# callback declarations
public delegate bool callbackDelegate(int iEvent, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string SomeString);
private callbackDelegate callbackDelegateInstance;

// instantiating and calling the callback in C#
callbackDelegateInstance = new callbackDelegate(CallbackHandler);
DLLCallbackFunction(callbackDelegateInstance);

// C# callback handler
private bool CallbackHandler(int iEvent, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string SomeString)
{
    // SomeString only contains characters up until the null char
}
```

Is there a way to return the entire string, including null chars from the dll?

I do have access to dll and gui code.

Comment: This is normal, LPWSTR is a zero-terminated string.  You'll have to declare it as IntPtr and marshal it yourself.  You do now get to solve the problem that the pinvoke marshaller doesn't know how to solve: how long is the string?  If you can change the native code then use BSTR instead.

Comment: i have the string length in the dll.

what's the purpose of BSTR?

can you provide and example of the IntPtr marshaling?

Comment: Don't be helpless, type "what is a bstr" in a google query.  And document carefully how we are supposed to know how long the string is if you want sample code.

Comment: i meant why BSTR in this context, not in general.

Comment: @alexsd BSTR because the pinvoke marshaller can do all the work for you. You just need `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BSTR)]` and you are done. On the native side you use `SysAllocStringLen` if you have a Unicode string, and `SysAllocStringByteLen` if you have ANSI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could marshal it as a raw byte array instead of an LPTSTR. If your data is not a constant size, you will have to add an additional length parameter.

The delegate would be declared something like this:

```
 public delegate bool callbackDelegate(int iEvent, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 2)] byte[] data, int dataCount);
```

And on the unmanaged side:

```
typedef void (__stdcall *callbackDelegate)(int iEvent, const char* data, int size);
```

Comment: thanks!  this worked.  just had to change to this SizeParamIndex = 2.

Comment: @user1580523 oh right, you mean SizeParamIndex = 2? My mistake.